# JSF 2.2, Richfaces 4.3 deployment error in Weblogic 12c

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2, weblogic12c

I am deploying my application with JSF 2.2 and Richfaces 4.3 in Weblogic 12c(using jdk 1.7). There is JSF error during deployment. Am pasting all my relevant code below.

Please let me know any suggestions to resolve this error. 
Is there any way to avoid ***jsf.spi.injection.provider_not_found*** error? And subsequently the javax.faces.FacesException?

**PS:** The application deploys and works fine in Tomcat 7.0

### Weblogic deployment log

```
####<Jul 30, 2014 6:53:37 PM EDT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application> <lsdz0010> <dt1-stnd-instance1> 
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1406760817033> 
<**jsf.spi.injection.provider_not_found**> 
<JSF1030: The specified InjectionProvider implementation 'com.bea.faces.WeblogicInjectionProvider' cannot be loaded.> 

####<Jul 30, 2014 6:53:51 PM EDT> <Warning> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <lsdz0010> <dt1-stnd-instance1> 
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1406760831934> 
<jsf.config.webconfig.param.deprecated> 
<JSF1025: [/IGATE2DATATOOL] Context initialization parameter 'facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD' is deprecated.  
The option will still be configured, but please use 'javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD' in the future.> 

####<Jul 30, 2014 6:53:52 PM EDT> <Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <lsdz0010> <dt1-stnd-instance1> 
<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1406760832397> 
<BEA-000000> <Critical error during deployment: 
**javax.faces.FacesException: Error parsing config file zip:....war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar!/META-INF/csv.xml**
    at org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parse(ClientServiceConfigParser.java:79)
    at org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser.parseConfig(ClientServiceConfigParser.java:48)
    at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.createClientScriptService(ValidatorModule.java:65)
    at org.richfaces.application.ValidatorModule.configure(ValidatorModule.java:60)
    at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.init(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:27)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.createFactory(InitializationListener.java:130)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStart(InitializationListener.java:68)
    at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.processEvent(InitializationListener.java:152)
```

### weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.1.2</wls:weblogic-version>
     <wls:context-root>IGATE2DATATOOL</wls:context-root>
     <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>package.that.conflicts.*</wls:package-name>
             <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
             <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
             <wls:package-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
         <wls:prefer-application-resources> 
            <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name> 
            <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name> 
            <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>  
            <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
            <resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.spi.FacesConfigResourceProvider</resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-resources>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

### faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
.
.
</faces-config>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
...
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
</web-app>
```

### Jar's in - WEB-INF/lib

```
javax.faces-2.2.6.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.3.5.Final.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.3.5.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.3.5.Final.jar
```

Comment: HAve you run a checksum on that jar from where you download it ?

Comment: I never did that till now. is there any web url where i can do this?

Comment: Since the stacktrace is pointing to the jar fo the richfaces it is most probably an error when downloading the file (corrupt file) so you can go to a maven web repository and download it again. Here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.richfaces.ui/richfaces-components-ui/4.3.5.Final I see that they don't give a md5 to check so just downlod it and compare the size with the one you have.

Comment: I downloaded the jar richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar from the mvnrepository link. It has the same size 6933kb as my jar in WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar

Answer (score 0):

This looks like jar is corrupt. However  RichFaces yet to support JSF2.2 version. Hence please use JSF2.1 version. Please refer [here](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12310341&version=12324641) for release note of Richfaces 4.3.7 which says upgraded to support Mojarra 2.1.28. Once you resolve the Jar issue you will get version not supported error. As per [link](http://www.bleathem.ca/blog/2014/05/richfaces-437final-release-announcement.html) RichFaces would support JSF2.2 in version 4.5

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Richfaces 4.3 doesn't support JSF 2.2 yet. I will try to use JSF 2.1 instead, as the link says RF4.3 was upgraded to support mojarra 2.1. Also i found that Weblogic 12c currently supports JSF 2.1 in the link [JSF in WL12c](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WBAPP/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#WBAPP198)